# lampp not working with i3 window manager

Tags: web, i3

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I installed the i3 window manager and have become pretty comfortable with it.

And yesterday, When I tried to use Lampp for web dev, it didn't work. The window manager was the last thing on my mind, and thus I created a new file and tried to access it, but nothing really worked.

Then, as a longshot, I logged out and logged in again into a Gnome session, and it worked!

Thus, lampp is not working with the i3 window manager.

I got the error `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when I tried to access a project stored in the directory `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` (just to give background, I am a power user and have used Lampp for a long time now and have never faced this problem, and it's not a problem with the setup, as I have already checked all the settings and the exact settings are working in the Gnome session).

The following commands are the ones that I used.

1. `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`
2. `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/` (Ensuring that access denied error is not thrown by the browser)

Comment: This [software](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html?ModPagespeed=noscript). I'm no web developer or anything but I've installed the 64bit v. vanilla + security script, and loaded the default welcome page(with status) in the browser with the demos. I'm on Arch though but I use _i3_. Could you provide more detail into what I could try out to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Learn Please use code formatting only for code, not to emphasize random words.